# Symbol lookup errors in (Qt?) dynamically linked libraries

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, kde, dynamic-linking, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10

**Problem:**
For some days now I have been getting Errors like this when opening some applications:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

Some applications affected are

- texstudio shows
  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev`
- IPython's `qtconsole` shows
  `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK12QStorageInfo11displayNameEv`
- konsole (KDE's terminal emulator - I'm using Unity though) shows 
  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5ItemViews.so.5: undefined symbol: ...`
- granatier (a KDE game), KSysguard and KAddressbook also show errors in `KF5` libraries
- also fail
- VLC seems to be affected too since it says there is something wrong with Qt 4 (see below)

**Qt**
all of this errors seem to come from Qt linked libraries ("Qt" appears in most filenames and most symbol names). AFAIK KDE ist baed on Qt, which would explain why all KDE applications fail.
It seems to affect both Qt 4 and 5

**Possible Origin**
The day this problems appeared I had enabled `wily-proposed` packages in the Ubuntu "Software &  Updates" System application. I interrupted the upgrade and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59443/how-can-i-revert-back-from-an-upgrade-to-the-proposed-repository) to roll it back.

After this I had a [similar problem with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518638/unable-to-import-ssl-on-linux) but it went away eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it seems the source of the problem was that I had Qt linked libraries like `libQt5Core.so.5` in `/usr/local/lib`. When I remove them everything worked again.
I've read that the package manager doesn't put any libraries there, so it was probably me who did a dumb mistake.